# Set the font of PPT text from VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to copy the excel content to PPT. using this command

```
  `pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteHTML, Link:=msoFalse  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetAEile
  Set myShape = pptSlide.Shapes(pptSlide.Shapes.Count)
    If myShape.Height <> ExcRng.Height Then
      myShape.Table.ScaleProportionally ExcRng.Height / 285
      End If`
```

While I am doing it sets the font of the content gets bigger or smaller depending on the amount of text in the shape.

Can some one tell me if I can fix the size of the font to "8" irrespective of the amount of content.

Since its not a textarea but just a  shape.

Answer (score 0):

Shapes containing text in Powerpoint have the property Autosize:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange().TextFrame.Autosize  = ppAutoSizeNone
```

With this you can make the text stick to the size you determine in

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange().TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size
```